# How I download & install GlassFish server on netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, glassfish

I tried to download the glassfish server but this error came out.

[image: AddServerInstance]

Comment: SUGGESTION: just download the .zip file, and then register Glassfish in NetBeans after you've extracted it.  ALSO:  You're going to develop your app in Java, correct?  Why did you add a C++ tag?

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using? Release 8.2 (which requires JDK 7 or JDK 8) is no longer supported as far as I know, so any downloads from official links will be unreliable. Regardless, a possible workaround for your problem (as per the previous comment) is to manually download GlassFish using your browser (i.e. outside of NetBeans), then add it as a server from your local download.